# MYSQL Difference between ( field1, field2 ) = (x,y) vs field1= x AND field2 = Y

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, mysql-select-db

I have a table studentDB with below fields

`select sid, sname, sDOB from Student`

I have seen this is many place, what is difference between **(xx,yy)** vs **AND**, and which one is more performance wise better

`select * from Student where (sid,sname) = (101,'foo')`

vs

`select * from Student where sid = 101 AND sname = 'foo'`

And also what is name of this operator **()** when using for matching?

Comment: There's no difference. That's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row constructor comparison is legal in SQL syntax, but in versions of MySQL 5.5 and earlier, this syntax did not support index optimization, so it was not encouraged.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/row-constructor-optimization.html

By now, all supported versions of MySQL do support index optimization for row constructor comparison. The older versions that lack this feature are past their end-of-life, so you shouldn't be using those old versions anyway. Therefore there's no reason to avoid this syntax anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`(sid,sname)`  is called a "tuple" and some database engines support them in varied degrees. MySQL 8 does it quite well.

Now, there's no difference between those two expressions when using equality. However, tuples can be quite useful for inequalities. For example:

```
select * from t where (a, b) <= (1, 0)
```

is different from:

```
select * from t where a <= 1 and b <= 0
```

When tuples are used the comparison of elements is done in sequence, one after the other. See example of differences at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nm9h3i3TvDtfKHPLRj6gRw/1).

Answer (score 0):

2013-12-03 MySQL 5.7.3 changelog:

> The optimizer now is able to apply the range scan access method to
> queries of this form:
>
> `SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ( col_1, col_2 ) IN (( 'a', 'b' ), ( 'c', 'd' ));` Previously, for range scans to be used it was necessary for the
> query to be written as:
>
> `SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE ( col_1 = 'a' AND col_2 = 'b' ) OR ( col_1 = 'c' AND col_2 = 'd' );` For the optimizer to use a range scan, queries
> must satisfy these conditions:
>
> Only `IN` predicates can be used, not `NOT IN`.
>
> There may only be column references in the row constructor on the IN
> predicate's left hand side.
>
> There must be more than one row constructor on the IN predicate's
> right hand side.
>
> Row constructors on the IN predicate's right hand side must contain
> only runtime constants, which are either literals or local column
> references that are bound to constants during execution.
>
> EXPLAIN output for applicable queries will change from full table or
> index scan to range scan. Changes are also visible by checking the
> values of the
> [Handler_read_first](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_first),
> [Handler_read_key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_key),
> and
> [Handler_read_next](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Handler_read_next)
> status variables.

(I have no info on whether MariaDB has picked up the optimization.)